# Is there any time limitation for a single sync call in Eloqua?

Tags: mule, bulk-load, eloqua

I need to fetch 1000k records from Eloqua to mule esb,I make the below 3 calls to Eloqua to fetch data :

1. Create the export definition
2. Synchronize the outgoing data into a temporary staging area
3. Retrieve the data

As the vCore limitation i make first 2 calls once and last call so many times, like first iteration fetch 20k records and process update into salesforce. In second iteration next 20k records.

The issue i face is after making 30th call/iteration payload retried from eloqua is 'null', Still around 400k records are there in eloqua but could not fetch.

It took 12 hours to complete 29 calls, is there any time limitation in Eloqua ? like one sync call is expired in 12 hours like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the **dataRetentionDuration** field in the export definition response. It seems to be 12 hours by default. Try creating the export with a bigger value.

From the latest docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-bulk-2.0-contacts-exports-post.html

**Request**

```
POST /contacts/exports
Content-Type: application/json 
{
    "name": "Contact Lead Score Export",
    "fields": {
        "Rating": "{{Contact.LeadScore.Model[1].Rating}}",
        "Profile": "{{Contact.LeadScore.Model[1].ProfileScore}}",
        "Engagement": "{{Contact.LeadScore.Model[1].EngagementScore}}",
        "EmailAddress": "{{Contact.Field(C_EmailAddress)}}"
    },
    "dataRetentionDuration": "PT48H"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "name": "Contact Lead Score Export",
    "fields": {
        "Rating": "{{Contact.LeadScore.Model[1].Rating}}",
        "Profile": "{{Contact.LeadScore.Model[1].ProfileScore}}",
        "Engagement": "{{Contact.LeadScore.Model[1].EngagementScore}}",
        "EmailAddress": "{{Contact.Field(C_EmailAddress)}}"
    },
    "dataRetentionDuration": "PT48H",
    "uri": "/contacts/exports/29588",
    "createdBy": "Api.User",
    "createdAt": "2015-08-19T20:51:28.8201911Z",
    "updatedBy": "Api.User",
    "updatedAt": "2015-08-19T20:51:28.8201911Z"
}
```

Comment: Hi, How can it be configurable to 48 hours ?

Comment: I updated the request in the answer to include "dataRetentionDuration": "PT48H". I hope it's helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

When [retrieving sync data](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-bulk-2.0-syncs-%7Bid%7D-data-get.html) the default limit is 1000; however, the maximum could be set to 50,000. If setting the limit query parameter to 50000, you could retrieve 400,000 records with 8 requests.

See this tutorial for some more details and examples - [Retrieving large volumes of data](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/BulkAPI/Tutorials/Retrieving_Large_Volumes.htm).

Comment: I would go with loupatrick's recommendation. He's the expert in that API.